# Where's the code in the Linux kernel the implements open("/proc/self/fd/NUM")?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I always assumed that doing `open(/proc/self/fd/NUM, flags)` was equivalent to `dup(NUM)`, but apparently this is not the case! For example, if you `dup` a file descriptor, then set the new fd to non-blocking, this also affects the original file descriptor (because non-blocking state is a property of the file description, and the two file descriptors both point to the same file description). However, if you open `/proc/self/fd/NUM`, then you seem to get a new independent file description, and can set the non-blocking state of your old and new fds independently. You can even use this to get two file descriptions referring to the same anonymous pipe, which is otherwise impossible ([example](https://gist.github.com/njsmith/ba7a7c1033d46895ea6e552cbec59141)). On the other hand, while you can `dup` a socket fd, `open("/proc/self/fd/NUM", flags)` fails if NUM refers to a socket.

Now I'd like to be able to see how this works for other types of special file, and answer questions like "what permission checking is done when re-opening a file this way?", so I was trying to find the code in Linux that actually implements this path, but when I started reading `fs/proc/fd.c` I quickly got lost in a maze of twisty operations structs, all different.

So my question is: can anyone explain the code path followed by doing `open("/proc/self/fd/NUM", flags)`? For concreteness let's say that `NUM` refers to a pipe and we're talking about the latest kernel release.

Comment: Interesting question. It seems like the magic happens in [proc_fd_link](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.1/source/fs/proc/fd.c#L138), used to get what `/proc/self/fd/NUM` is a link to. It just copies the `struct path*` (dentry, basically) from the open file table. That leaves it up to whatever created the original `struct path` to implement functionality to open the dentry's inode, in this case [open_fifo](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.1/source/fs/pipe.c#L883) from `fs/pipe.c`. Also TIL: Linux has a "pipefs" where all the pipes live :O

Answer (score 4):

A comment suggests a look at proc_fd_link and that's a good idea. If you have trouble following how the code can get there, you can help yourself with systemtap. Here is a magic script:

```
probe kernel.function("proc_fd_link") {
    print_backtrace();
}
```

Running it while opening a file from under fd/ gives:

```
 0xffffffffbb2cad70 : proc_fd_link+0x0/0xd0 [kernel]
 0xffffffffbb2c4c3b : proc_pid_get_link+0x6b/0x90 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb36341a : security_inode_follow_link+0x4a/0x70 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb25bf13 : trailing_symlink+0x1e3/0x220 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb25f559 : path_openat+0xe9/0x1380 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb261af1 : do_filp_open+0x91/0x100 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb26fd8f : __alloc_fd+0x3f/0x170 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb24f280 : do_sys_open+0x130/0x220 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb24f38e : sys_open+0x1e/0x20 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb003c57 : do_syscall_64+0x67/0x160 [kernel] (inexact)
 0xffffffffbb8039e1 : return_from_SYSCALL_64+0x0/0x6a [kernel] (inexact)
```

In proc_pid_get_link we see:

```
/* Are we allowed to snoop on the tasks file descriptors? */
if (!proc_fd_access_allowed(inode))
        goto out;
```

aaaand

```
/* permission checks */
static int proc_fd_access_allowed(struct inode *inode)
{
        struct task_struct *task;
        int allowed = 0;
        /* Allow access to a task's file descriptors if it is us or we
         * may use ptrace attach to the process and find out that
         * information.
         */
        task = get_proc_task(inode);
        if (task) {
                allowed = ptrace_may_access(task, PTRACE_MODE_READ_FSCREDS);
                put_task_struct(task);
        }
        return allowed;
}
```

clearly, you need the same perms as if you were attaching with ptrace.

Finally, why does opening a socket fail? strace shows ENXIO being returned. A quick git grep ENXIO fs/*.c reveals:

```
static int no_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
        return -ENXIO;
}
```

Checking how the code ends up using no_open is left as an exercise for the reader. Also note systemtap can be used for printf-like debugging without modifying the source code. It also can be placed on 'return' from functions and report the error code.