# socket fd from /proc/$PID/fd seems invalid

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I know `pid` of the process, and I need to obtain socket `fd` used by it, so I look for it in `/proc/$pid/fd`, for instance:

```
$ ls -la /proc/1442/fd | grep socket
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Jan 23 16:22 7 -> socket:[21807]
$
```

Now, when I pass the value 7 representing socket descriptor to `getsockopt()` I'm getting `EBADF` error. Is it not allowed to do this from another process even with root privileges?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

File descriptors are per-process. They are not shared between processes.

If you want to access a file descriptor owned by another process, you can sometimes `open()` the path in `/proc/<pid>/fd` to get a copy of it. However, this only works on normal files; it doesn't work on sockets. ([This question addresses the internal details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068862/wheres-the-code-in-the-linux-kernel-the-implements-open-proc-self-fd-num))

So, in short, no. There's no straightforward way I'm aware of for one process to "take over" a socket from another process, without that process's cooperation.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you mean for example :  `fd = open("/proc/1442/fd/7", O_RDONLY)` where fd will be _real_ socket descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can "takeover" a socket being root, look:

[image]